# require_relative doesn't pull the variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, require

Been learning Ruby from _why's book and I tried to recreate his code, but it doesn't work.

I have a **world.rb** file ;

```
puts "Hello World"

Put_the_kabosh_on = "Put the kabosh on"
code_words = {
    starmonkeys: "Phil and Pete, thouse prickly chancellors of the New Reich",
    catapult: "Chunky go-go",
    firebomb: "Heat-Assisted Living",
    Nigeria: "Ny and Jerry's Dry Cleaning (with Donuts)",
    Put_the_kabosh_on: "Put the cable box on"
}
```

And in my other file, pluto.rb ;

```
require_relative "world"

puts "Hello Pluto"
puts code_words[:starmonkeys]
puts code_words[:catapult]
puts code_words[:firebomb]
puts code_words[:Nigeria]
puts code_words[:Put_the_kabosh_on]
```

I know my `require_relative`works, because if I run pluto.rb without the hash part (just puts `"Hello World"`), Hello World gets printed!

Comment: If you're expectecting the code_words local variable to exist in pluto.rb, then it won't. This is the way require(_relative) works

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Within a Rails app, you should put these in a YAML file. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables are local: they don't survive across a `require`. Global variables (`$code_words`), constants (`CODE_WORDS`) and instance variables (`@code_words`) do. Class variables (`@@code_words`) do as well, but you'll get a warning. Of these, constants are the least smelly; but it would be better if you put them in a module to namespace them:

```
module World
  CODE_WORDS = { ... }
end
```

and in `pluto.rb`:

```
require_relative "world"
puts World::CODE_WORDS[...]
```